# Cannot install Watch app

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit

When trying to test a Watch app on the Watch, in XCode I get the following warning

> Watch App xcodeproj TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY contains a value incompatible
>   with the target type.

[image]

Looking at the Device logs, it says:

```
(Error) WatchKit: validateWatchKitApplicationInfoDictionary, invalid UIDeviceFamily value
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is this in your WatchKit app or extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Modify Targeted Device Family

1. Open file PROJECT.xcodeproj in your project folder
2. Open file project.pbxproj
3. Replace value of TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY: "4" for watchkitextension, "1,4" for watchkitapp
4. Replace value of "TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY[sdk=iphonesimulator*]" = "1,4" for watchkitapp

e.g.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Your Watch Extension should have a TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY of **iPhone** whereas the Watch App target should have TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY of **1,4** like this:

[image: Xcode device family settings for apple watch]

I had a similar problem on a project that was created with an Xcode beta. I ended up creating a new test project and going through side by side and comparing all the settings.

Comment: The funny part is that is you switch to "iPhone/iPad" you will lose "1,4" and there's no way to get it back from the dropdown menu (there's no 1,4 option in the menu)!