# Apple Watch invalid UIDeviceFamily

Tags: ios, watchkit, provisioning, apple-watch

I've written an Apple watch application. When I was working at local, it was perfect. But now I am trying to build it with a signed provision. My provision and info.plist's are correct, I checked twice.

I can send the standard iOS application to my device. But When I am trying to send to Apple watch application from IPhone->Apple Watch... I take this error,

> Watchkit:validateWatchKitApplicationInfoDictionary, invalid
>   UIDeviceFamily value... Error Domain=com.apple.watckit.errors Code=7
>   "invalid info dictionary"

Does anyone knows the solution of this error?

Comment: Have you checked this SO question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30067864/cannot-install-watch-app

Comment: Yes I had. For watch extension build settings it is OK. But this setting is comes with XCode 6.3(SDK 8.3) for the watch app. But I am using XCode 6.2. So I dont have build settings part for the watch app.